NextJS Network Error when opening the console
This is my first Next.js application, and I'm encountering an error. During development, whenever I tried to check the responsiveness using the browser, I consistently faced an Internet Error upon pressing CTRL+R to reload the page. Initially, I thought it was an issue with my localhost, so I tried hosting my project on Hostinger, but I encountered the same problem. The website loads well initially, but when I navigate to certain pages, they don't load, and when I refresh the page, I get an internet error.
This is my next.config.mjs :
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
   // output: 'export',
    images: {
        domains: ['trophe.net', 'localhost'],
        unoptimized: true
    },
    trailingSlash: true, 
};

export default nextConfig;


The .htaccess :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule> 

My dependencies :
"dependencies": {
    "@formspree/react": "^2.5.1",
    "next": "^14.2.5",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-share": "^5.1.0",
    "sharp": "^0.33.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }

My hosted website is : https://trophe.net/
Try to access /team and reload the page to reproduce the error.
I checked the documentation and found nothing about this type of error. I tried to recreate the project.
